# add items to a combo box in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to add items to the drop down list of a combo box in a datagridview?

Answer (score 2):

The `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` has an `Items`-Property which you can use like this:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn theColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.YourDataGrid.Column("YourColumn");
theColumn.Items.Add("NewItem");
theColumn.Items.Add("NewItem2");
```

**Edit:** Do not forget that you need to cast the Column to the right type, because they're a of the generic `DataGridViewColumn`-Type.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a combobox in the DataGridView, you can add items in to your combobox that in DataGridView like this:

1. Create DataGridViewComboboxCell object
2. Add your items into your DataGridViewComboboxCell object that created
3. Assign created object to your empty combobox

Step 1

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cmbbox = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
```

Step2

```
cmbbox.Items.Add("A");
cmbbox.Items.Add("B");
cmbbox.Items.Add("C");
```

Step3

```
int emptyComboBoxRowsIndex = 0;//you change with your index;
int emptyComboBoxCellIndex = 0;//you change with your index;
DataGridView1.Rows[emptyComboBoxRowsIndex].Cells[emptyComboBoxCellIndex] = cmbbox;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of achieving your goal, here's one of them, that just might do the trick

This method consists of two steps.

1) Create a ComboBox & Add contents to it

2) Add the Items if The ComboBox to your DataGridComboBox

Step 1)

```
ComboBox CB= new ComboBox();
CB.Items.Add("A"); 
CB.Items.Add("B");
CB.Items.Add("C");
CB.Items.Add("D");
CB.Items.Add("E");
```

Step 2)

```
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)MyDataGrid.Columns["MyDataGridColumnName"]).DataSource = CB.Items ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Linq To Sql**

DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

**Add Grid :** gvRecord

**Linq Query**

```
  var details = (from x in dc.Details
                 orderby x.Datetime descending
                 select x).ToList();



  var combocolumnA = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                    combocolumnA.HeaderText = "ID";
                    combocolumnA.ValueMember = "id";
                    combocolumnA.DataSource = details;
                    gvRecord.Columns.Add(combocolumnA);
                    combocolumnA.Width = 100;

  var combocolumnB = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                    combocolumnB.HeaderText = "Name";
                    combocolumnB.ValueMember = "Name";
                    combocolumnB.DataSource = details;
                    gvRecord.Columns.Add(combocolumnB);
                    combocolumnB.Width = 150;
```